# Gherkin for CYPRESS - How to format GHERKIN for long test cases with multiple validation points throughout the test

Tags: cypress, gherkin, reusability, scenarios

I understand that within this framework users are unable to call scenarios within scenarios.
I am trying to create End to End test cases where there are validation points at multiple stages of the test.

Using 'bad' gherkin syntax the process for the scenario would be something like:

Given Item A exists

When User processes Item

Then Warning is displayed

When User accesses Item

Then Warning is not displayed

When User finalises Item

Then Item status = "CURRENT"

And Record Status = "COMPLETED"

The first thing I considered was breaking the scenario into 3 distinct GWT scenarios.

That is fine.

However suppose I now want to create a new end to end scenario that can re-use one of the 3 scenarios created (as you would re-use a function).

How do I do this without duplication of Gherkin code?

I cannot use Background as the sections that I require to re-use are in the middle of the execution.
Steps prior and after may be different.

IN SUMMARY: I am trying to re-use a GWT scenario that is common for many end to end scenarios  where the end to end scenarios are inherently different.

Any feedback or assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers and thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean. I have done some "meta" scenario's. For example there are ones that test login, maintaining details and creating an account that are very fine grained. Then I have scenario's that test things further along the way, assuming that the happy path has been taken up to that point. So imagine having a scebnario called:

```
The user is logged in and has successfully created an account and is at the add product screen
```

For that, in the step definition, I would just combine function calls with hardcoded values:

```
@When("^The user is logged in and has successfully created an account and is at the add product screen$")
    def addProducts(String val) {
        navLibrary.loginAsUser("user", "password")
        navLibrary.createAccount("some", "params", "you", "need")
        navLibrary.navToProducts("some param")
    }
```

And then start with the finer details in new separate steps. You have to think system design, and cascading. For me it meant a lot of initial rework as the tests started growing, but now it's a breeze. Pick the right level of reusability. It is testing code, so it doesn't have to subscribe perfectly to all the programming precepts. It must work, and it must be low maintenance in the long run.
I didn't use Cypress though. My tests are in Groovy with Selenium and Cucumber.